# JQuery MouseUp reporting CHILD element

Tags: jquery, events, html, mouseup

I'm getting an odd behavior with my "mouseup" event. I have a div inside a div. The mouseup event is attached to the OUTER div, yet if I happen to click on the INNER div, the e.target is set to the child div instead of the parent div that has the event.

Is this normal?

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

So a:

```
$("body").on('mouseup', '.parent',myMethod);
```

Reports an e.target as child if it's exactly clicked.

Comment: _"Is this normal?"_ Yes. That's the event propagating up the DOM.

Comment: Propagating I understand, but shouldn't it get to the parent? To note, there is no even on the child. Wouldn't that mean that all divs would report a click regardless of event assignment? I should note I have hundreds of event handlers with children, and none of them do this.

Comment: Check out the explanation http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: @j08691, added a CW to this. That link you posted has a very nice explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the difference between `.target` and `.currentTarget`

> This property of event objects is the object the event was dispatched on. It is different than event.currentTarget when the event handler is called in bubbling or capturing phase of the event.

- `event.target`        // A reference to the target to which the event was originally dispatched.
- `event.currentTarget` // A reference to the currently registered target for the event.

Worth testing:

```
$("body").on('mouseup', '#parent1', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target,e.currentTarget);
});
```

**Demo [jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/wdGfE/1/)**
**Demo [plain javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/uAqz5/)**

---

More reading:

**MDN**: [**event.target**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target)
**MDN**: [**event**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)
**jQuery** (an [**explanation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) about Direct and delegated events)

Comment: SOLVED! OMG, I can't believe I've been using the wrong target. DERP! Thank you so much.